# Unable to get json data

Tags: javascript, json

Below is my JavaScript code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $.ajax({
         url: "http://api.wunderground.com/api/f40719f4c7835e02/history_20060405/q/CA/San_Francisco.json",
        dataType : "jsonp",
        success : function(parsed_json) {
            var maxtempi = parsed_json['dailysummary']['maxtempi'];
            //var temp_f = parsed_json['dailysummary']['maxtempi'];
            alert("Maxtempi is" + maxtempi);
        }
    });
});
```

I'm trying to get the `maxtempi` under `dailysummary`, but unable to do so. Whats wrong with my code ?

Comment: do a console.log( parsed_json ) to see what is actually being returned with the Ajax call.

Comment: console.log(maxtempi) and onsole.log( parsed_json ); nothing was printed out in my console. @jeff

Comment: what does console.log( parsed_json ) return?

Comment: change jsonp to json - that URL does NOT return jsonp

Comment: @jeff nothing as well.

Comment: @jeff, you could actually open the URL, it returns data.

Comment: @JaromandaX changed. refreshed my page and nothing happening

Comment: check the developer tools network tab

Comment: I just fiddeled your code and got this error `This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.` Changed that and some of the variables, and it works fine https://jsfiddle.net/pf1gfm4o/2/

Comment: use `parsed_json.history.dailysummary[0]['maxtempi']`

Answer (score 2):

You're accessing the wrong property:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://api.wunderground.com/api/f40719f4c7835e02/history_20060405/q/CA/San_Francisco.json",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(parsed_json) {
      console.log(parsed_json);
      var maxtempi = parsed_json.history.dailysummary[0].maxtempi;
      //var temp_f = parsed_json['dailysummary']['maxtempi'];
      alert("Maxtempi is" + maxtempi);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. But do you mind to explain how do you know that you need to access dailysummary[0] first ?

Comment: Open your browser's console (F12), run the code snippet and you'll see `parsed_json` object printed, you can now see exactly how it's structured and you can see `dailysummary` is an array of 1 element. Or you can read the [source json](https://api.wunderground.com/api/f40719f4c7835e02/history_20060405/q/CA/San_Francisco.json) directly (it's uglier but that works too). `console.log`ging objects you don't know is the easiest way to know how to read it and what it contains.

Answer (score 0):

You have to  access `parsed_json["history"]["dailysummary"][0]["maxtempi"]` for `maxtempi`.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 
              $.ajax({
              url :"http://api.wunderground.com/api/f40719f4c7835e02/history_20060405/q/CA/San_Francisco.json",
              dataType : "json",
              success : function(parsed_json) {
                
              var maxtempi = parsed_json["history"]["dailysummary"][0]["maxtempi"];
              //var temp_f = parsed_json['dailysummary']['maxtempi'];
              alert("Maxtempi is " + maxtempi);
              }
              });
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```